# Make center long TextView in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make position center of long textView in layout at android.I used android:gravity="center" in layout but it didn't for the TextView has a long text.How can I solve this problem?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/memorialvodafonebackground_2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Ekranda adınız göründükten sonra hastanemizi      değerlendirmenizden memnuniyet duyacağız"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add this properties android:gravity="center" to your TextView also.

Comment: Unrelated to the question you should use the Unit "sp" for Textsize, not "dp"

Comment: thank you Haresh and Spring Braker.. it works

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

for `TextView`

`android:gravity` - sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

[`android:layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) - sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Ekranda adınız göründükten sonra hastanemizi      değerlendirmenizden memnuniyet duyacağız"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Ekranda adınız göründükten sonra hastanemizi      değerlendirmenizden emnuniyet duyacağız"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
```

Comment: you can fix your text size  android:textSize="Text Size"